# How to interpret memory addresses?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

When I print out the address of different memory regions I get values like 0xda2280, 0x7f8a494f9010 etc. And these point to different bytes in memory.

1) But why are the ranges so large? Would each address in between have been addressable that would mean that I'd have over 140TB of memory. How do I interpret this?

2) Most of the times the addresses are grouped within high and low addresses (heap and stack). But sometimes I see three different regions, clearly separated. What is this third memory region?

Comment: Have you Googled a bit? First hit on "linux memory management": http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/mm/memory.html This is quite a complex subject, that cannot be easily answered. Also, it is not about programming, so it doesn't belong here.

Comment: Yes I was aware that the virtual memory was quite a bit larger than the physical one, though I wasn't aware that It was that much larger.

And I am unable to find an explanation to why sometimes large objects are allocated in the middle of the (virtual) address space. I would expect the same behavior of a clear division of stack and heap being concentrated on their respective ends, no matter how large the address space is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `/proc/<pid>/smaps` to see all the different addresses ranges the process has mapped.  You'll find that something like an initialized  global variable has an address that corresponds to the range mapped to the executable file itself, stack variables from the stack map, and small malloced data from the heap map.  The address of a function in a shared library (e.g. `&printf`) will appear in that lib's text segment mapping.

There are different ways to create a mapped range, such as `brk()` to change the heap size and `mmap()` to map parts of the file into memory.  The latter is how the code and data segments of executable and shared libraries are placed into memory.

Rather than allocate ranges one right after the other, different kinds of allocations have different regions they come from.  This is why you see the ranges scattered throughout the 64-bit address space.

The reason a large malloc might have a different kind of address than a small one is because of how malloc is allocating the memory.  The small allocations usually come from the heap, which is at a lower address in typical x86_64 systems.  But a large allocation doesn't come from the heap.  If it did, then when it was freed there would be this huge hole where it was with other data still allocated before and after it.  Inefficient.  It's part of a problem known as fragmentation.  So very large allocations use `mmap()` to map a new region of memory just for the one allocation.  This "anonymous mapping" as it's called will come from a different region than the heap and so you get an address that looks different.

Answer (score 0):

The memory addresses you see are just virtual. The operating system has a memory-manager that basically is a dynamic map between the virtual addresses the applications use and the physical memory.

Also, to increase security, some of these memory addresses might be random between every time the application is executed, to make it harder to exploit buffer-overflow bugs etc.

Comment: My understanding was that they were random, but still contained within roughly the same addresses. Now, say we have addresses [0-100], I have values on the stack roughly (0-10). And heap say (80-100). What I am witnessing is addresses at (50-55) as well, I would think this is a bit extreme for randomization. But you think this can be explained by this randomization too?

Comment: Take a look at /proc/self/maps (or replace self with the PID of your program) to see the current memory layout)